# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "n", value = 3L) : replacement has 1 row, data has 0 When using ggplot2 geom_violin()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to generate violin plot for different groups. The data looks like this:

```html
               V1     V2    V3
1  150105R1-2-C05  7.001  4541
2  150105R1-2-C05  5.001  5992
3  150105R1-2-C05  7.001  5499
4  150105R1-2-C05  3.001  3021
5  150105R1-2-C05 21.001 15760
6  150105R1-2-C05  3.001  3246
7  150105R1-2-C05 19.001 13972
8  150105R1-2-C05  4.001  4537
9  150105R1-2-C05  3.001  2936
10 150105R1-2-C05  7.001  4664
11 150105R1-2-C05  8.001  6755
12 150105R1-2-C05  8.001  7618
13 150105R1-2-C05  4.001  4093
14 150105R1-2-C05  7.001  5322
15 150105R1-2-C05 23.001 14706
16 150105R1-2-C05  8.001  4881
17 150105R1-2-C05  3.001  2881
18 150105R1-2-C05 18.001 13280
19 150105R1-2-C05  9.001  6738
20 150105R1-2-C05  7.001  5540
```

My command is simple:

```
R<-read.table("./data.txt")

ggplot(R,aes(V1,log(V2),fill=factor(V1),width=1))+geom_violin()+theme_bw()+theme( panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),legend.position = "none",axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.4,hjust=1))+ylim(1,8)
```

I have tried many times (including manually change R$V2 into numeric type) but each time I get the following error:

```
"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "n", value = 3L) :    replacement has 1 row, data has 0 "
```

My R version is 3.1.2, and the command works if I change "geom_violin" to "geom_boxplot()".

Does anyone know what happens here? Is it a bug of violin plot? Or is my data in the wrong format?

Comment: Not reproducible here, the code shows a violin plot (R version 3.1.1 + ggplot2_1.0.0).

Comment: works on R-devel, ggplot2 1.0.0.  Can you show us `sessionInfo()` ?